# tkinter Canvas - <Enter> Bind infinite loop with stacked canvas elements

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am creating a roulette simulator using the python tkinter 8.5 framework (due to certain restrictions) and am relatively new to the concept of binding callback commands.

When the user hovers over a certain rectangle in my canvas, the desired effect is for a circle to appear at its centre (representative of a chip). 
My current source code has this working nicely, however I encounter issues when the user hovers over the circle while within the rectangle. It produces an infinite loop, calling the enter and exit callbacks for the rectangle alternately.

Below is my class for creating the board piece (rectangle) and handling its user interaction (please excuse the questionable indentation).

```
from tkinter import *
import uuid

class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Board_Piece:

    def clicked(self, event):

        print("{} was clicked.".format(self.id))

    def on_entry(self, event):

        print("Entered box")

        chip_side_length = 20

        x1, y1 = (self.top_left.x+(self.width/2)-chip_side_length/2), (self.top_left.y+(self.height/2)-chip_side_length/2)
        x2, y2 = x1 + chip_side_length, y1 + chip_side_length
        self.bet_token_circle = self.parent.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="yellow")

    def on_exit(self, event):

        print("Exitted box")

        self.parent.delete(self.bet_token_circle)

    def enable(self):

        self.rectangle = self.parent.create_rectangle(self.top_left.x, self.top_left.y, self.top_left.x+self.width, self.top_left.y+self.height, fill=self.bg, outline='white', tags="{}".format(self.id))

        text_displacement = 0
        x1, y1 = (self.top_left.x+(self.width/2)-text_displacement/2), (self.top_left.y+(self.height/2)-text_displacement/2)
        self.parent.create_text(x1, y1 ,fill="white",font="Arial 10 bold", text=self.text)

        self.parent.tag_bind(self.id, "<Button-1>", self.clicked)
        self.parent.tag_bind(self.id, "<Enter>", self.on_entry)
        self.parent.tag_bind(self.id, "<Leave>", self.on_exit)

    def __init__(self, parent, x, y, width, height, text, bg):

        self.parent = parent
        self.bg = bg
        self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex
        self.top_left = Point(x, y)
        self.width = width
        self.text = text
        self.height = height

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000, bg="#237B1A")
canvas.pack()

board_piece = Board_Piece(canvas, 100, 100, 50, 50, "8",'red')

board_piece.enable()

mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So that we can duplicate your problem, please create a [mcve], and make sure the indentation is correct.

Comment: Of course, I've made the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a leave-event, if cursor reaches chip.
Chip is deleted by leave-event and cursor is on rectangle again.
Chip is created by enter-event and cursor is on chip again and so on.

To avoid this both events only should happen, if the outer border of rectangle is passed, for example in this way:

```
def on_entry(self, event):      
    if (event.x <= self.top_left.x or event.x >=self.top_left.x + self.width) or (event.y <= self.top_left.y or event.y  >= self.top_left.y + self.height):
        print("Entered box")
        chip_side_length = 20
        x1, y1 = (self.top_left.x+(self.width/2)-chip_side_length/2), (self.top_left.y+(self.height/2)-chip_side_length/2)
        x2, y2 = x1 + chip_side_length, y1 + chip_side_length
        self.bet_token_circle = self.parent.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="yellow")        
    else:
        pass

def on_exit(self, event):       
    if self.top_left.x < event.x < self.top_left.x + self.width and self.top_left.y < event.y < self.top_left.y + self.height:
        pass       
    else:
        print("Exitted box")
        self.parent.delete(self.bet_token_circle)
```